# Recommended way to verify client part of spring cloud contract in Jersey application

Tags: jersey, spring-cloud-contract

I have written a spring cloud contract in an server application running spring boot. This part is correctly generating the stubs into my local repo. Now I want to verify this contract from a client application running Spring 3.1 and Jersey.

As a workaround I evaluated the possibility of manually unpacking the stub jar into the mapping file and launch the verification using WireMockClassRule as it is done in [this link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/master/spring-cloud-contract-tools/spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin/src/test/resources/functionalTest/sampleJerseyProject/loanApplicationService/src/test/groovy/org/springframework/cloud/LoanApplicationServiceSpec.groovy)

Is there some other easy way of reusing the AutoConfigureStubRunner to do this work for me, and still don't need to add a dependency to Spring Boot?

***EDIT:***
I have been able to download and unpack stubs jars using maven `dependency:unpack` plugin, and later to run them using wiremock (similar to what is done [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/master/spring-cloud-contract-tools/spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin/src/test/resources/functionalTest/sampleJerseyProject/build.gradle)). The only problem that I still need to solve is how to dynamically pick the stub latest version. By using the maven dependency plugin I always need to provide the artifact version.

Comment: If you want to run the thing as a separate process you can use the Stub Runner Boot (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_stub_runner_boot_application) and allow it to download all stuff. If not you can use the JUnit Rule (I haven't checked it against Spring 3.1 though) - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_stub_runner_junit_rule .

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcin. I end up using the Jersey approach and used the dependency:unpack with LATEST in version to always download the last stub version

Comment: Can you describe your approach in more depth as an answer to this issue? That way it will be profitable for other people.

Comment: I finally did it, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that need to consume a stub jar at the client. The stub among othet things has a json containing the data that your contract provides to do the integration test. This json has a format used by wiremock to publish an endpoint similar to our real backend. So the following steps need to be taken:

**Download the stub jar from the repo to your local machine and copy it to wiremock internal folder**

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.1</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>unpack</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <artifactItems>
     <artifactItem>
      <groupId>com.yourbackend.contract</groupId>
      <artifactId>contract-service</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <classifier>stubs</classifier>
     </artifactItem>
    </artifactItems>
    <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
    <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
    <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
    <includes>META-INF/**/mappings/**</includes>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/mappings</outputDirectory>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note here that LATEST is set as the version of the stub to make sure that always the last stub jar is retrieved.

**Start wiremock server in localhost**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and then in the test

```
@ClassRule
WireMockClassRule wireMockRule = new WireMockClassRule(port);
```

**You are set, do the http calls in the tests**